# EventHandler inside loop for several Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, eventhandler

My code is creating multiple instances of a form with different controls and events. This is done while incrementing `i` to the total amount of forms. The aim is to add an event to a button control in the form. My forms are instances of `Ticker`, the subclass of `Form` that I have created.

The issue I have is that when I click on the button at run-time, the event handler kicks in and `i` is out of bounds as the loop has already finished.

A snippet of the code is below, the event handler is integrated into a loop incrementing `i` which also houses the switches. Any way for `thisObject` to be equal to the current active ticker while still keeping the event handler in the loop?
EDIT: I've provided the full class for better clarity. The section in question follows through the action_set>>email>>trigger>>click cases.

```
   public partial class DesktopTickers : Form
    {
        public DesktopTickers(List<string> tickerArgs)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Opacity = 0;
            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            int totalTickers = tickerArgs.Count();

            Rectangle screenBounds = GetDpiSafeResolution();
            Size iconSizeDefault = this.Size;                                                         
            string iconDirectory = @"\\server\Tickers\";
            string iconSuffix = "_icon.png";
            string configDirectory = @"\\server\Tickers\";
            string configSuffix = ".txt";
            char paramDelimiter = ':';
            char controlDelimiter = '=';
            char[] controlSeparatorL = {'('};
            char controlSeparatorR = ')';
            char actionDelimiter = '=';
            char[] actionSeparatorL = {'('};
            char actionSeparatorR = ')';
            char propertyDelimiter = '-';
            int maxWidthDefault = iconSizeDefault.Width;                                                                             
            int maxHeightDefault = iconSizeDefault.Height;                                                                             
            Ticker[] tickers = new Ticker[tickerArgs.Count()];
            List<Control> controls = new List<Control>();

            for (int i = 0; i < tickerArgs.Count(); i++)                                                       
            {
                string tickerArg = tickerArgs[i];                                                               
                string tickerConfigPath = configDirectory + tickerArg + configSuffix;                           
                string tickerResourcePath = iconDirectory + @"\" + tickerArg + @"\";
                string tickerIconPath = tickerResourcePath + tickerArg + iconSuffix;
                tickers[i] = new Ticker(screenBounds, tickerArg, i+1, tickerArgs.Count(), iconSizeDefault, 
                                        maxHeightDefault, maxWidthDefault, tickerIconPath);
                string[] tickerConfigContents = File.ReadAllLines(tickerConfigPath);
                for (int j = 0; j < tickerConfigContents.Length; j++)               
                {
                    string thisConfigLine = tickerConfigContents[j];                                                    
                    int configParamEnd = thisConfigLine.IndexOf(paramDelimiter);                                        
                    if (configParamEnd < 0) { configParamEnd = 0; }
                    string tickerConfigParam = thisConfigLine.Substring(0, configParamEnd);                           
                    string tickerConfigValue = thisConfigLine.Substring(configParamEnd + 1);
                    switch (tickerConfigParam.ToLower())                                    
                    {   //TICKER LEVEL PARAMETERS
                        case "icon_width":
                            tickers[i].iconWidth = Convert.ToInt32(tickerConfigValue);
                            break;
                        case "icon_height":
                            tickers[i].iconHeight = Convert.ToInt32(tickerConfigValue);
                            break;
                        case "max_width":                                                    
                            tickers[i].maxWidth = Convert.ToInt32(tickerConfigValue);        
                            break;
                        case "max_height":                                                   
                            tickers[i].maxHeight = Convert.ToInt32(tickerConfigValue);  
                            break;
                        case "control_set":   
                            for (int k = j + 1; k < tickerConfigContents.Length; k++)        
                            {   //CONTROL LEVEL PARAMETERS
                                string thisControlLine = tickerConfigContents[k]; 
                                if(thisControlLine == "end") { break; }
                                int controlParamEnd = thisControlLine.IndexOf(controlDelimiter); 
                                string thisControlType = thisControlLine.Substring(0, controlParamEnd);
                                string thisControlDetails = thisControlLine.Substring(controlParamEnd+ 1);
                                thisControlDetails = thisControlDetails.Replace(controlSeparatorR.ToString(), "");
                                string[] controlProperties = thisControlDetails.Split(controlSeparatorL, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); 
                                switch (thisControlType.ToLower()) 
                                {   //CONTROL TYPE LEVEL PARAMETERS
                                    case "image":                  
                                        PictureBox thisImage = new PictureBox(); 
                                        for (int l = 0; l < controlProperties.Length; l++)
                                        {
                                            string thisProperty = controlProperties[l];
                                            int propertyParamEnd = thisProperty.IndexOf(propertyDelimiter);
                                            string propertyType = thisProperty.Substring(0, propertyParamEnd - 1);
                                            string propertyValue = thisProperty.Substring(propertyParamEnd + 2);
                                            switch (propertyType.ToLower())
                                            {   //PROPERTY LEVEL PARAMETERS
                                                case "file":
                                                    try { thisImage.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(tickerResourcePath + propertyValue); }
                                                    catch { thisImage.BackgroundImage = thisImage.ErrorImage; }
                                                    break;
                                                case "bounds":
                                                    char[] pointDelimiter = { ',' };
                                                    string[] boundsValues = propertyValue.Split(pointDelimiter);
                                                    Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(
                                                                            new Point(Convert.ToInt32(boundsValues[0]), Convert.ToInt32(boundsValues[1])),
                                                                            new Size(Convert.ToInt32(boundsValues[2]), Convert.ToInt32(boundsValues[3])));
                                                    thisImage.Bounds = bounds;
                                                    break;
                                                case "layout":
                                                    switch(propertyValue.ToLower())
                                                    {
                                                        case "stretch":
                                                            thisImage.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
                                                            break;
                                                        case "zoom":
                                                            thisImage.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Zoom;
                                                            break;
                                                        case "tile":
                                                            thisImage.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Tile;
                                                            break;
                                                        case "center":
                                                            thisImage.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Center;
                                                            break;
                                                        default:
                                                            thisImage.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.None;
                                                            break;
                                                    }
                                                    break;
                                                case "id":
                                                    thisImage.Name = propertyValue;
                                                    break;
                                            }
                                            tickers[i].Controls.Add(thisImage);
                                            thisImage.Show();
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    case "label":
                                        Label thisLabel = new Label();
                                        for (int l = 0; l < controlProperties.Length; l++)
                                        {
                                            string thisProperty = controlProperties[l];
                                            int propertyParamEnd = thisProperty.IndexOf(propertyDelimiter);
                                            string propertyType = thisProperty.Substring(0, propertyParamEnd - 1);
                                            string propertyValue = thisProperty.Substring(propertyParamEnd + 2);
                                            thisLabel.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
                                            switch (propertyType.ToLower())
                                            {   //PROPERTY LEVEL PARAMETERS
                                                case "text":
                                                    thisLabel.Text = propertyValue;
                                                    break;
                                                case "font":
                                                    char fontDelimiter = ',';
                                                    int fontSplitIndex = propertyValue.IndexOf(fontDelimiter);
                                                    string fontName = propertyValue.Substring(0, fontSplitIndex);
                                                    string fontSize = propertyValue.Substring(fontSplitIndex + 1);
                                                    int fontSizeNum = int.Parse(fontSize);
                                                    thisLabel.Font = new Font(propertyValue, fontSizeNum);
                                                    break;
                                                case "bounds":
                                                    char[] pointDelimiter = {','};
                                                    string[] boundsValues = propertyValue.Split(pointDelimiter);
                                                    Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(
                                                                            new Point(Convert.ToInt32(boundsValues[0]), Convert.ToInt32(boundsValues[1])),
                                                                            new Size(Convert.ToInt32(boundsValues[2]), Convert.ToInt32(boundsValues[3])));
                                                    thisLabel.Bounds = bounds;
                                                    break;
                                                case "id":
                                                    thisLabel.Name = propertyValue;
                                                    break;
                                            }
                                            thisLabel.Show();
                                            tickers[i].Controls.Add(thisLabel);
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    case "button":
                                        Button thisButton = new Button();
                                        for (int l = 0; l < controlProperties.Length; l++)
                                        {
                                            string thisProperty = controlProperties[l];
                                            int propertyParamEnd = thisProperty.IndexOf(propertyDelimiter);
                                            string propertyType = thisProperty.Substring(0, propertyParamEnd - 1);
                                            string propertyValue = thisProperty.Substring(propertyParamEnd + 2);
                                            switch (propertyType.ToLower())
                                            {
                                                case "text":
                                                    thisButton.Text = propertyValue;
                                                    break;
                                                case "font":
                                                    char fontDelimiter = ',';
                                                    int fontSplitIndex = propertyValue.IndexOf(fontDelimiter);
                                                    string fontName = propertyValue.Substring(0, fontSplitIndex);
                                                    string fontSize = propertyValue.Substring(fontSplitIndex + 1);
                                                    int fontSizeNum = int.Parse(fontSize);
                                                    thisButton.Font = new Font(propertyValue, fontSizeNum);
                                                    break;
                                                case "bounds":
                                                    char[] pointDelimiter = { ',' };
                                                    string[] boundsValues = propertyValue.Split(pointDelimiter);
                                                    Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(
                                                                            new Point(Convert.ToInt32(boundsValues[0]), Convert.ToInt32(boundsValues[1])),
                                                                            new Size(Convert.ToInt32(boundsValues[2]), Convert.ToInt32(boundsValues[3])));
                                                    thisButton.Bounds = bounds;
                                                    break;
                                                case "id":
                                                    thisButton.Name = propertyValue;
                                                    break;
                                            }
                                            thisButton.Show();
                                            tickers[i].Controls.Add(thisButton);
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    case "textbox":
                                        TextBox thisTextBox = new TextBox();
                                        for (int l = 0; l < controlProperties.Length; l++)
                                        {
                                            string thisProperty = controlProperties[l];
                                            int propertyParamEnd = thisProperty.IndexOf(propertyDelimiter);
                                            string propertyType = thisProperty.Substring(0, propertyParamEnd - 1);
                                            string propertyValue = thisProperty.Substring(propertyParamEnd + 2);
                                            thisTextBox.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
                                            switch (propertyType.ToLower())
                                            {   //PROPERTY LEVEL PARAMETERS
                                                case "text":
                                                    thisTextBox.Text = propertyValue;
                                                    break;
                                                case "font":
                                                    char fontDelimiter = ',';
                                                    int fontSplitIndex = propertyValue.IndexOf(fontDelimiter);
                                                    string fontName = propertyValue.Substring(0, fontSplitIndex);
                                                    string fontSize = propertyValue.Substring(fontSplitIndex + 1);
                                                    int fontSizeNum = int.Parse(fontSize);
                                                    thisTextBox.Font = new Font(propertyValue, fontSizeNum);
                                                    break;
                                                case "bounds":
                                                    char[] pointDelimiter = { ',' };
                                                    string[] boundsValues = propertyValue.Split(pointDelimiter);
                                                    Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(
                                                                            new Point(Convert.ToInt32(boundsValues[0]), Convert.ToInt32(boundsValues[1])),
                                                                            new Size(Convert.ToInt32(boundsValues[2]), Convert.ToInt32(boundsValues[3])));
                                                    thisTextBox.Bounds = bounds;
                                                    break;
                                                case "id":
                                                    thisTextBox.Name = propertyValue;
                                                    break;
                                            }
                                            thisTextBox.Show();
                                            tickers[i].Controls.Add(thisTextBox);
                                        }
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        case "action_set":
                            for (int k = j + 1; k < tickerConfigContents.Length; k++)                                        
                            {   //ACTION LEVEL PARAMETERS
                                string thisActionLine = tickerConfigContents[k];                                             
                                if (thisActionLine == "end") { break; }
                                int actionParamEnd = thisActionLine.IndexOf(actionDelimiter);       
                                string thisActionType = thisActionLine.Substring(0, actionParamEnd);
                                string thisActionDetails = thisActionLine.Substring(actionParamEnd + 1);
                                thisActionDetails = thisActionDetails.Replace(actionSeparatorR.ToString(), ""); 
                                string[] actionProperties = thisActionDetails.Split(actionSeparatorL, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                                Control thisObject = new Control();
                                switch (thisActionType.ToLower())                                                          
                                {   //ACTION TYPE LEVEL PARAMETERS
                                    case "email":
                                        //email requires trigger, objectid, action to send email, email action params
                                        for (int l = 0; l < actionProperties.Length; l++)
                                        {
                                            string thisProperty = actionProperties[l];
                                            int propertyParamEnd = thisProperty.IndexOf(propertyDelimiter);
                                            string propertyType = thisProperty.Substring(0, propertyParamEnd - 1);
                                            string propertyValue = thisProperty.Substring(propertyParamEnd + 2);
                                            string emailDomain = "";
                                            string emailServer = "";
                                            int emailPort = 0;
                                            string emailTemplate = "";
                                            string emailRecipient = "";
                                            switch (propertyType.ToLower())
                                            {
                                                case "domain":
                                                    emailDomain = propertyValue;
                                                    break;
                                                case "server":
                                                    emailServer = propertyValue;
                                                    break;
                                                case "port":
                                                    emailPort = Convert.ToInt32(propertyValue);
                                                    break;
                                                case "file":
                                                    emailTemplate = tickerResourcePath + propertyValue;
                                                    break;
                                                case "recipient":
                                                    emailRecipient = propertyValue;
                                                    break;
                                                case "object":
                                                    thisObject = tickers[i].Controls.Find(propertyValue, false).FirstOrDefault() as Control;
                                                    //thisObject = objects[0];
                                                    break;
                                                case "trigger":
                                                    tickers[i].SetEmailProperties(emailDomain, emailServer, emailPort, emailTemplate, emailRecipient);
                                                    switch(propertyValue.ToLower())
                                                    {
                                                        case "click":
                                                            thisObject.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler((sender, e)
                                                                => tickers[i].SendEmail_Event(sender, e));
                                                            break;
                                                    }
                                                    break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
                tickers[i].Show();
            }
        }


        private Rectangle GetDpiSafeResolution()
        {
            using (Graphics graphics = this.CreateGraphics())
            {
                return new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), new Size((Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width * (int)graphics.DpiX) / 96
                , (Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height * (int)graphics.DpiY) / 96));
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Not enough context, but you could try to look if [Form.ActiveForm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activeform(v=vs.110).aspx) could help to solve your problem

Comment: Form.ActiveForm didn't help me when I looked into it because it returns a Form, not a Ticker:Form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a capture issue. You need to capture the value of `i` when the form is created and keep this value when you create the event handler. This can be done simply by creating a new variable `iValue` or `tickerInd` while creating the form and using this variable rather than `i` in the event handler code.

I am writing this answer a little bit speculatively. Please provide a larger code snippet which will allow us to see the creation code for the form and the handler. But I believe that your current code is as follows. The part that I marked as "code based on i" is the code snippet that you have currently provided.

```
for (var i = 0; i < formCount; ++i)
{
    var form = new Ticker();
    form.Button.OnClicked += () =>
        {
            //code based on i
            doSomething(i);
        };
}
```

It needs to be as follows:

```
for (var i = 0; i < formCount; ++i)
{
    var formInd = i;
    var form = new Ticker();
    form.Button.OnClicked += () =>
        {
            //code based on i
            doSomething(formInd);
        };
}
```

Edit: You need to change the following code:

```
case "click":
    //replace i with tickerInd, this will capture the current value of i
    var tickerInd = i;
    thisObject.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler((sender, e)
      => tickers[tickerInd].SendEmail_Event(sender, e));
break;
```

Note: Your code seems to need some refactoring. First of all, you don't really need `Ticker[] tickers`, you can simply do the following:

```
public DesktopTickers(List<string> tickerArgs)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < tickerArgs.Count; ++i)
    {
        var tickerArg = tickerArgs[i];
        var ticker = new Ticker(...);
        //your whole initialization code goes here
        //replace all "tickers[i]" with "ticker"
        ticker.Show();
    }
}
```

Afterwards, you can do further refactoring by moving this initialization into `Ticker` constructor and then further divide it into initializtion methods.

Comment: I hesitated to find he best scope for the code snippet as a lot of the variables used are fairly scattered. I guess the best way is to provide the whole class. You can find my original snippet by following the action_set case through to email, trigger and click.

Comment: I have looked at your code. The issue is exactly as I and @GeirGrusom has predicted. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @Can Bud, the idea behind the switches is to make the Tickers incredibly customisable using text files for each one, being able to map events to controls, hence why the event handler is created in the loop.

Comment: You're welcome. Creating the handler based on the configuration is great. But you do not really need to do this inside this loop. You can move the whole logic into `Ticker`'s own constructor, where you will not need `Tickers[i]`.

Comment: Yeah I can see that now. I should have realised that I would inevitably have code that would get touched at runtime that doesn't belong in the ticker initialisation loop. Thanks!

Comment: @Can_Bud I've refactored the code, but I still have an issue with adding the event handlers. It breaks saying there is no instance of the object. My code is similarto as follows. I think the issue is that as it is in a loop, actnObject takes multiple values for the instance of Ticker


`Control eventControl = this.Controls.Find(this.actnObject, false).FirstOrDefault();


eventControl.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(this.SendEmail_Event);`

I've also tried adding the actnControls to a list and then iterating through the list in the load event code but same issue

Comment: Hello @Chrayfish, I don't know what `actnObject` is. I haven't seen your refactored code. I am not sure what you mean by "no instance of the object", but looking at the small bit of code you have provided, you might be getting a null reference exception. Maybe you can ask a new question for this error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I entirely understand the issue, but it seems you have a problem with scoping more than loops.

In C# 4 there was a bug in the compiler which scoped `foreach` and `for` variables such that when they were closed it would always be the last value assigned. This was fixed in C# 5.

If `ticker[i]` in `(sender, e) => tickers[i].SendEmail_Event(sender, e)` always ends up being out of scope, it could be because your iterator variable is declared outside the scope of the loop.

```
int i = 0;
var funcs = new Func<int>[100];
do 
{
    funcs[i] = () => i;
}while(++i < 100);

Assert.That(funcs[0](), Is.EqualTo(0));
```

This test will fail, because they all close over i, which in effect will be 100 when the loop ends. To fix this you need a variable that is in the inner scope (and therefore in this case unique to each iteration):

```
int i = 0;
var funcs = new Func<int>[100];
do 
{
  int closedInt = i;
  funcs[i] = () => closedInt;
}while(++i < 100);

Assert.That(funcs[0](), Is.EqualTo(0));
```